# Using Wget To Download File Every Five Minutes

Tags: linux, date, unix, wget

Currently, I'm trying to use the `date` command (NOT crontab) to manually download a file that is uploaded to a server every five minutes.

I realize that `date -u +%M --date="5 minutes ago"` will display the time from 5 minutes ago but, I'm looking for a way **to go back in 5 minute increments**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 5 can be any number:

```
for n in {0..1440..5}; do date -u --date="$n minutes ago"; done
```